# Image of closed subvariety of incidence variety under two projections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n\times (\mathbb{P}^n)^\vee$ be the incidence variety. Then $I$ can be realized as $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Suppose I have a subvariety $Z$ of $I$ which is a $n+1$ to $1$ cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$, such that $p_{1*}(\mathcal{O}_Z)=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\oplus\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}$. I am wondering what can we say about the  image of $Z$ under $p_2$? It seems to me that $Z$ should be a $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ bundle over an curve in $(\mathbb{P}^n)^\vee$.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Small quibble: the direct image of $\mathcal O$ under a finite morphism of degree $d$ is a rank $d$ vector bundle. However you have equated the pushforward under $p_1$ which has degree $n-1$ with the bundle $\mathcal O \oplus \Omega$ which has rank $n+1$ (I am assuming that by $\Omega$ you mean the cotangent bundle).

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks, you are right! I edited accordingly.

Comment: OK, that makes sense now. Is your reasoning behind the conjectured projective bundle structure just that for $[H] \in p_2(Z)$, the fiber $p_2^{-1}([H])$ is basically just the hyperplane $H$ itself?

Comment: @TabesBridges Not quite. The said situation happens when we look at a Mukai system $X$ of genus 2 (n=2). Then there is a map $X\to I$ by considering the relative canonical map. $Z$ is the divisor in $im(X)$ so that $\mathcal{O}(2Z)$ is the ramification divisor.

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with the notion of a Mukai system. You might want to add some further background material.